# C++ template for classes with static method

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, refactoring, cocos2d-x

I'm currently programming a game using cocos2dx engine and I have a level manager that keeps track of the current level and the scene that needs to be loaded. I want to avoid long if statements, such as this:

```
Scene* scene;
if (level == 1)
{
      scene = Game_Scene1::createScene();
}
else if (level == 2)
{
      scene = Game_Scene2::createScene();
}
else if (level == 3)
{
      scene = Game_Scene3::createScene();
}
(...)
else if (level == 10)
{
      scene = Game_Scene10::createScene();
}

Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(TransitionFade::create(0.5, scene, Color3B(0,0,0)));
```

The `screateScene()` method is a static method

```
static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();
```

What could I do to "remove" the if statement? So it would look something like this:

```
Scene* scene = getScene(level, sceneClass::createScene());
```

and it would take the correct class (that is: `Game_Scene1`, `Game_Scene2` etc.)

Is there a nice solution for such problem? The title says template but I'm not really sure if the solution for this is a template.

Comment: If `level` is a runtime value, you can't (just) use a template, since it would need a compile-time value. But are you sure you've got your design right? Those numbered classes are a bit of a warning flag.

Comment: Why is the method static? This looks like dynamic polymorphism, i.e., a base `GameScene` class with `virtual createScene()` method. Then you create a factory or a factory method to create the right instance based on the level number.

Comment: Or, maybe, it even looks like a `Kit` (prototype based `Factory`). Why are there separate classes for scenes on the different levels? This kind of stuff should be dynamic, not static.

Comment: How about `switch`? How about using a table/map?

Comment: @iksemyonov I'd do that if I was programming in Java and it was the only way. I support @joachim's solution: a constant container (map, array ...) filled with `std::function`s.

Comment: Typical polymorphism example, declare this method to be `virtual` not a `static`. Because the object type is known at runtime the `template` will not help you much in here.

Comment: but the static `createScene()` method is a cocos2dx method and it needs to be static :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution would be to used a table of pointer functions.

You could declare your table as

```
typedef cocos2d::Scene *(*PtfCreateScene)();
PtfCreateScene tab[10];

tab[0] = Game_Scene1::create_scene;
tab[1] = Game_Scene2::create_scene; ...
```

Using this solution you can then call the associated create_scene function using `level` as an index. Thus avoiding the if branchings .

```
scene = tab[level - 1]();
```

You will have to check the correctness of the index to avoid out of memory access.

Hope I answered your question. Don't hesitate to ask if you need more explanation.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot! I did it a bit different (so it fits more in my code) but still Your solution was the key to success ;)

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;)